# Implementing AES-256 with 1024 byte key

Tags: java, spring, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to write Java code which will do AES-256 encryption/decryption using 1024 byte key. I looked into Internet for the implementation and there are many way to implement.

I took a look at the following tutorials:

1. http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/tutorial-76-implement-aes-256-encryptiondecryption-using-java/
2. https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364

but didn't find what steps are the required. So my question is What I need to to start encryptiopn/decryption. Isn't specifying algorithm (AES-256) and secret key is enough? What are the APIs I have to call?

---

Also I am planning to write a utility class with two method exposed to encrypt and decrypt. I am planning to initialize all these setting in constructor. So suggest me the best way to put this class in my Spring web app.

Comment: doesn't AES-256 have 256 in it's name because of the key size being 256 bits?

Comment: Is it? I thought 256 is size in which data is grouped for encoding. and 1024 is size of key we use.

Comment: 256 is the key size...

Comment: When not sure, look up the standard.

Comment: With cryptography, you first need a clear understanding what you are doing before you start to implement anything. Use cases, attack vectors and a key management scheme are minimal requirements before you can create or choose a protocol, let alone implementing the protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AES is only defined for 128, 192 and 256 bit keys](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf). These are called AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256 respectively. So you can't use a 1024 byte key with AES.

The AES block size (what you described as "size in which data is grouped for encoding") is always 128 bits for AES. Rijndael, a subset of which became AES, supports 256 bit blocks in addition to 128 bit blocks. Neither Rijndael nor AES have been defined for 1024 byte keys.

If you have such large key material you can reduce it to 256 bits using a hash like SHA-256, or a proper KDF like HKDF. Obviously this will reduce the security level to 256 bits, but that's still plenty. The reason why AES is not defined for larger keys is that a conventional computer will never be able to brute-force a 256 bit key. See [How much would it cost in U.S. dollars to brute force a 256 bit key in a year?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year) on crypto.se.

Comment: Is there any Java code I can start to with. There are different implementation. I want to being with simple one. I am looking more specifically to know what the inputs will be like (key,keysize etc..), What Java API that I can use?

Comment: @user4035943 Use something that supports AES-GCM. And make absolutely sure that you **never reuse a (key, nonce) pair**.